# how to get background color in html variable for a shiny app in r?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I am creating a `shiny` app and trying to get **top two fields** (Name & location) of the `html` **popup** to have a **orange background color**.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)
# library(htmlwidgets)
# library(htmltools)
library(readxl)
library(RCurl)

URL <- "https://www.mohfw.gov.in/pdf/PMJAYPRIVATEHOSPITALSCONSOLIDATED.xlsx"
download.file(URL, destfile = "../../timesnow_PMJAYPRIVATEHOSPITALSCONSOLIDATED.xlsx",method = "curl")

# Data
ind_vaccination_leaflet <- readxl::read_xlsx(path = "../../timesnow_PMJAYPRIVATEHOSPITALSCONSOLIDATED.xlsx",
                                             sheet = 1)
```

```
# Creating variable with html tags & background doesn't work
ind_vaccination_leaflet <- ind_vaccination_leaflet %>% 
    mutate(label_display = paste(
    "<body style='background-color:orange;'>",
        "<h2>", "Center: ", ind_vaccination_leaflet$`Name of the Vaccination Site*`, "</h2>",
        "<h3>",ind_vaccination_leaflet$`District*`, ", ", ind_vaccination_leaflet$`State*`, "</h3>",
    "</body>",
        "<p>", "Address: ", ind_vaccination_leaflet$Address, ", ", ind_vaccination_leaflet$`PinCode*`, "</p>",
        "<p>", "Mobile: ", ind_vaccination_leaflet$`Mobile Number`, "</p>",
        "<p>", "Contact Person: ", ind_vaccination_leaflet$`Contact Person`, "</p>"
    )
    )
```

**Issue:** When I plot it using below code then I don't get the **orange** `background` in the first two rows of the popup:

```
m <- leaflet() %>% 
  setView(lat = 26.64510, lng = 80.17012, zoom = 5) %>% 
  addTiles(group = "OSM") %>% 
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.DarkMatter, group = "Dark") %>% 
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron, group = "Light") %>%
  addProviderTiles("Stamen.Terrain", group = "Terrain") %>% 
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery", group = "WorldImagery") %>% 
  addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("OSM","WorldImagery","Dark","Light","Terrain")) 
  
m %>% 
  addCircleMarkers(
    lng = ind_vaccination_leaflet$lon,
    lat = ind_vaccination_leaflet$lat,
    label = lapply(ind_vaccination_leaflet$label_display, htmltools::HTML),
    color = "midnightblue",
                        weight = 1,
                        radius = 8
  )%>% 
  
  addMiniMap(tiles = providers$OpenStreetMap, width = 120, height=80)
```

[image]

I am not really a **coder nor ui/html** person so not sure where is it going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try switching `body` to `div`.

You can experiment with HTML code much easier in an online editor, e.g. [this one](https://html5-editor.net/)

Comment: Thanks alot @mnist for sharing the link & suggestion. That worked !!